# Show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos x \text{dx}=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin x \text{dx}$

Tags: calculus, integration

> Show that $\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\cos x \ \text{d}x=\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin x \ \text{d}x$ using integration by parts.

For the LHS, I got:
$-e^{-x} \cos x-\int e^{-x} \sin x \ \text{d}x$

I'm not sure how to show that the RHS integral is equal to this...

Comment: Integration by parts works watch out the sign of the integral part (derivative of cosine is minus sine) and non integral part goes to 0 both at zero and at infinity

Comment: If you integrate by parts twice you can even derive the value of the integral

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Integrating by parts twice for each of the following gives

\begin{align}
\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \cos x \, dx &=\left.-\frac 12e^{-x}(\sin x+\cos x) \right\vert_0^\infty= \frac 12 \\
 \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin x \, dx &= \left.\frac 12e^{-x}(\sin x-\cos x) \right\vert_0^\infty = \frac 12
\end{align}

Comment: You don't even need to do that. The question asks to show they're equal, not to compute the values.

Comment: Computing the values is only one way to do it. If you have a solution that does not require computing said values, you are more than welcome to present your solution here.

Comment: I'm just saying there can be a faster way. The solution I'm talking about is posted by egreg.

Answer (score 16):

Here is an answer that does not use integration by parts:

$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} e^{ix} dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \cos x dx + i \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin x dx = {1 \over i-1} e^{(i-1)x} \big|_0^\infty = {1 \over 2} (1+i)$$ hence
$$\int_0^\infty e^{-x} \cos x dx = \int_0^\infty e^{-x} \sin x dx = {1 \over 2}$$

Comment: Why the downvote?

Comment: I am truly curious. Why the second downvote? The answer is correct, simple and is not the only answer that does not use integration by parts.

Answer (score 13):

$$\int_{0}^{+\infty}(\cos x-\sin x) e^{-x}\,dx = \left.e^{-x}\sin x\right|_{0}^{+\infty} = 0.$$

Comment: Jack D'Aurizio: nice. +1

Comment: I believe this is the only answer that shows *why* they are the same. Integration by parts solves it, but fails in this respect. +1

Answer (score 11):

You don't need to compute the integrals to show that they're equal. First of all, for any bounded function $f$ on $[0,\infty)$, the integral
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}f(x)\,dx
$$
converges absolutely, because, if $|f(x)|\le k$, we have $|e^{-x}f(x)|\le ke^{-x}$ and
$$
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\,dx
$$
converges.

Now, integrating by parts,
$$
\int_0^{\infty}e^{-x}\cos x\,dx=
[e^{-x}\sin x]_0^{\infty}-\int_0^\infty (-e^{-x})\sin x\,dx=
\int_0^\infty e^{-x}\sin x\,dx
$$
because, clearly,
$$
\lim_{x\to\infty}e^{-x}\sin x=0.
$$

Comment: egreg: nice. +1

Answer (score 7):

firstly you look the LHS:

$$\int \:e^{-x}\cos \left(x\right)dx$$
Now you substitute with $u=-x:\quad \quad du=-1dx,\:\quad \:dx=\left(-1\right)du$:
So,
\begin{align*}
=\int \:e^u\cos \left(x\right)\left(-1\right)du \\
=\int \:-e^u\cos \left(x\right)du \\
\end{align*}
Substitute: $u=-x\quad \Rightarrow \quad \:x=-u$
$$\Rightarrow =-\int \:e^u\cos \left(-u\right)du =-\int \:e^u\cos \left(u\right)du$$
$\mathrm{Apply\:Integration\:By\:Parts}:\quad \int \:uv'=uv-\int \:u'v$
$$=-\left(e^u\sin \left(u\right)-\int \:e^u\sin \left(u\right)du\right)$$
$$=-\left(e^u\sin \left(u\right)-\left(e^u\left(-\cos \left(u\right)\right)-\int \:e^u\left(-\cos \left(u\right)\right)du\right)\right)$$
$$=-\left(e^u\sin \left(u\right)-\left(-e^u\cos \left(u\right)-\int \:-e^u\cos \left(u\right)du\right)\right)$$
$\mathrm{Isolate}\:\int \cos \left(u\right)e^udu$
$$=-\frac{e^u\left(\sin \left(u\right)+\cos \left(u\right)\right)}{2}$$
$\mathrm{Substitute\:back}\:u=-x$ , simplify and add a constant:
$$=-\frac{e^{-x}\left(\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{2}+C$$
Now calculate the limes for $x\to\infty$:
$$\lim _{x\to \infty \:}\left(-\frac{e^{-x}\left(\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{2}\right)=0$$
Now, the limes for $x\to 0+$:
$$\lim _{x\to \:0+}\left(-\frac{e^{-x}\left(\cos \left(x\right)-\sin \left(x\right)\right)}{2}\right)=-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\Rightarrow 0-\left(-\frac{1}{2}\right) = \frac{1}{2}$$

I hope you can do this for the RHS :)